# How to truncate file geodatabase tables with Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, python-2.6

I need to truncate file geodatabase tables (1 or all) with Python. What is the code for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use [Delete Rows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n6000000) method in arcpy. from Arcgis Resource Center:

**Delete Rows (Data Management)**

> Summary
>
> Deletes all or the selected subset of rows from the input.
>
> If the input rows are from a feature class or table, all rows will be
> deleted. If the input rows are from a layer or table view with no
> selection, all rows will be deleted.

consider this caution:

> If run against a layer or table view that does not have a selection,
> the operation cannot be undone using undo/redo.

**Example Code:**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.CopyRows_management("accident.dbf", "C:/output/accident2.dbf")
arcpy.DeleteRows_management("C:/output/accident2.dbf")
```

Answer (score 10):

As of 10.1, Esri has added **[Truncate Table (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000016z000000)**. It will remove all records from a table, regardless of a table view selection, and does not support versioned tables. It is much faster, though.

Esri's sample code for truncating all tables in a geodatabase:

```
# Set the workspace.
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/work/vancouver.gdb"

# Get a list of all the tables.
tableList = arcpy.ListTables()

# Loop through the list and run truncate
for table in tableList:
    arcpy.TruncateTable_management(table)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

wrksp = r"workspace"

env.workspace = wrksp


fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:

    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc, "fc_Temp")

    arcpy.DeleteRows_management("fc_Temp")
```

Comment: If the goal is truncation, DeleteRows is the wrong tool. Instead, use TruncateTable.  Note that code-only ("wall of code") questions get downvotes for failing to ask a Question; wall of code answers also fail to provide an Answer.